# Bind winforms datagridview rowheader

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagridrowheader

In C# Winforms `DataGridView` I am binding a List of class using the datagriview's `datasource` property. Is there a way to bind one of  the class property to the datagriview's `rowheader`?

I didn't want to `iterate` all the rows and add row header values one by one because I will have thousands of records so I wanted the rowheader to get the values from the binded class when I set the datasource.

For example I have this class and I want the rowheaders to show the Customer ID.

```
private class Customer
{
   public string CustomerID { get; set; }
   public string CustomerFirstName { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you have to implement datagridview's `OnPaint`-Method, where you paint the customer id in a loop. Once, I wanted to numerate my entries and I didn't find any other solution.